# gcc Assembly code output different than expected

Tags: c, gcc

I am new to c and gcc. I'm trying to follow along with an example in Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective. The author says that the following code when put into a file (code.c)

```
int accum = 0;
int sum(int x, int y)
{
    int t = x + y;
    accum += t;
    return t;
}
```

and using the gcc as follows to output an assembly code file

gcc -O2 -S code.c

will produce assembly code as follows

```
sum:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp,%ebp
 movl 12(%ebp),%eax
 addl 8(%ebp),%eax
 addl %eax,accum
 movl %ebp,%esp
 popl %ebp
 ret
```

However on my machine (OS: Ubuntu 10.4 x64) I get the following

```
    .file   "code.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  sum
    .type   sum, @function
sum:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
    add DWORD PTR accum[rip], eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   sum, .-sum
    .globl  accum
    .bss
    .align 4
    .type   accum, @object
    .size   accum, 4
accum:
    .zero   4
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Why am I seeing this difference?

Comment: Primarily because you used `-O2`. The examples are in that book are also almost all for 32 bit processors, so you'll need to get used to seeing differences when compiling on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Different GCC versions?

Answer (score 2):

Because the book is 11 years old and gcc has changed a great deal since it was written.

Comment: And OP is on 64-bit machine (rip reg)